problem getting stripe to collect payments in django
i'm working on a django rest project and it utilizes the stripe payment gateway. i've been getting the same error ever since. i try to initialize a payment for the user and the server responds with a 400 bad request error. i've tried everything i know about solving this issue
this is my views.py file
from django.shortcuts import render
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import Http404


# restapi imports
from rest_framework import status, authentication, permissions
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

# my api/models imports
from .models import Order, OrderItem
from .serializers import OrderSerializer


# Create your views here.
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([authentication.TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
def checkout(request):
    serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        paid_amount = sum(item.get('quantity') * item.get('product').price for item in serializer.validated_data['items'])

        try:
            charge = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                amount=int(paid_amount * 100),
                currency='usd',
                description='Charge from beats.com',
                source=serializer.validated_data['stripe_token'],
                payment_method_types=['card'],
            )

            serializer.save(user=request.user, paid_amount=paid_amount)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

and this is my serializers.py file
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Order, OrderItem


class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = (
            "price",
            "product",
            "quantity",
        )

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "address",
            "zipcode",
            "place",
            "phone",
            "stripe_token",
            "items",
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        items_data = validated_data.pop('items')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for item_data in items_data:
            OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, **item_data)
            
        return order

i think this is where my problems may lie

Can you share the error message returned from the Stripe API?
